# t-sql view conversion failed when filtering on converted column

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create view by filtering some table, and include some converted to different type column into select list. View filter excludes from result set rows in which this column can not be converted to that type. Then I select rows from this view and filter rows using this converted column. And I always get error `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '2aaa' to data type int`

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56fc10/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table _tmp_aaa (id int identity(1, 1), value nvarchar(max) not null)
go
insert _tmp_aaa (value) values ('1111'), ('11'), ('2aaa')
go

create view _tmp_v_aaa 
as 
select id, cast(value as int) as value from _tmp_aaa where value like '1%'
go
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from _tmp_v_aaa where value = 11
```

Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried some tricks... Obviously the optimizer tries to hand down your where criterium where it is not yet tranformed. This is one problem to be solved with a. multi-statement function. Their biggest disadvantage is the advantage in this case: the optimizer will not look into it, but just take their result "as is":

```
create function  fn_tmp_v_aaa()
returns @tbl table(id INT, value INT)
as 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @tbl
select id, cast(value as int) as value from _tmp_aaa where value like '1%'
RETURN;
END

select * from dbo.fn_tmp_v_aaa() where value=11;
```

Comment: Using table valued function which is not inline? Really? How poor performance it will have

Comment: I normally NEVER use multl-line functions... In this case it helps... But your solution with ISNUMERIC is better, I'll vote you up...

Comment: Thank you, i forget about functions. My data will never be so big that performance can be a problem

Answer (score 4):

Add to your view ISNUMERIC to check if string is numeric value:

```
CREATE VIEW _tmp_v_aaa 
AS 
SELECT
  id,
  [value] = CAST((CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([value]) = 1 THEN [value] ELSE NULL END) AS INT)
FROM _tmp_aaa 
WHERE [value] LIKE '1%' 
   AND ISNUMERIC([value]) = 1
```

Comment: Thank you, it is a solution. But my original view is more complicated and it using Regexps and cross apply's. So Shnugo solution fits better for me

Comment: ISNUMERIC is a poor choice to checking if value is a numeric/number , isnumeric returns true for values like `123e1`.

Comment: @M.Ali You mean ISNUMERIC is poor choice for checking if number is INT written in normal (non-expotential) form in string.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the execution plan , predicates are passed down to the table something like....

[image]

And your query gets translated to something like .....

```
select id, cast(value as int) as value 
from tmp_aaa 
where CONVERT(INT, value,0) like '1%'
 AND CONVERT(INT, value,0) = CONVERT(INT, 11,0)
```

Now if you run this query you will get the same error you get when you query against the view.

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '2aaa' to data type int.
```

When the predicate `CONVERT(INT, value,0) like '1%'` is converted , you have `INT` on one side of the expressions and varchar on another, INT being the higher precedence, sql server tries to convert whole expression to INT and fails hence the error message.